# How to query on a DateTime property of a DateTimeOffset in Realm .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xamarin.forms, realm

I have realm models that have a "Date" property, which is of type DateTimeOffset.

```
public class Log : RealmObject
{
    // other code omitted for brevity 
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get all objects where the date is of a specific day. I initially tried using linq queries like this

```
.All<Log>().Where(x => x.Date.DayOfYear == DateTimeOffset.Now.DayOfYear);
```

but realm throws

```
The left-hand side of the Equal operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm. 
Unable to process 'x.Date.DayOfYear'
```

because querying on nested properties in linq is not supported.
https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/806

I then tried using the Realm Query Language to accomplish the task

```
.All<Log>().Filter("Date.DayOfYear == $0", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.DayOfYear).FirstOrDefault();
```

but this throws an exception as well

```
Property 'Log.Date' is not an object reference
```

How is one expected to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

What your recording in Realm is actually a timestamp that includes the date information *as well as* the time information and even time zone offset!

It looks like this in Realm

2023-08-28T21:43:17.300Z

This means if you use equality to try to compare it to today for example, it will fail because today is generated today so even if the actual dates matches up, the time won't.

There are a number of solutions so let me cover a few at a high level.

1. If you don't care about times, you could store all dates with just the date components and set all times to 0. So for example, a users birthday. The time part probably isn't important so create timestamps that look like this

   2023-04-01T00:00:00.000Z

and that can be easily filtered, create the date you want to find, set it's time components to 0 and filter.

2. Have two managed properties; one with the actual timestamp (includes the time) and the other as a date formatted string like yyyy-mm-dd so then all date comparisons can be done using the string. Create a today, extract the yyyy, mm and dd, build a string and do the compare.
3. Use before and after... create a today and then a var for yesterday and one for tomorrow

   let foundDay = dateToSeachFor > yesterday and dateToSearchFor < tomorrow

Comment: In regards to this part of the answer, "This means if you use equality to try to compare it to today for example, it will fail because today is generated today so even if the actual dates matches up, the time won't.", I am not comparing the full time and date, simply the DayOfYear which is an int.

Comment: @Sev That's a good observation. But... that's not a direct option in a query. There is no ability to 'drill down' into a timestamp and compare just one part of it. It's all or none. e.g. That's why this code `Date.DayOfYear` is not valid within a query.

Comment: Is that not what the Realm Query Language is for? If I am reading the docs correctly I should be able to do that using RQL. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/#dot-notation

Comment: @Sev Unfortunately no. Dot notation is for drilling down into a Reams - *Objects* - properties, not into a property (unless that unto itself is another object). In other words; suppose a Realm object has a property to store a persons name `var personName = "Jay"`. A query can be done on strings that contain the letter 'y'. However, it cannot be done for 'y' at the second index in the string -> `personName[2].char == 'y'` is not valid. You can think of a Date property as a primitive (like a string or an Int) and is the smallest unit Realm handles.